# Disk read error after cloning a Windows partition to an Asus Laptop?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, asus-laptop

I bought Crucial BX100 for my Asus n53sv and cloned Windows partition to it. It doesn't boot, it says:

> A disk read error occurred Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart

The disk works fine when connected via USB case - thats how I cloned partitions to it. Bios seems to detect it as I see it in boot positions. What is wrong then?

Asus Bios is version 109, there is 115 now but it is from 2012 and the BX100 didn't exist then, so I think it won't help, but I can give it a try..

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to try the drive on another machine to see if it works?
Are you able to check and update if need be that the BIOS is up to date with the latest version?

Comment: I must have bought a new battery to do BIOS upgrade as it was broken. Bios is new now but it still doesnt work. I have the same SSD on Acer laptop and i made test: BX100 SSD from Acer boots in ASUS. BX100 from Asus doesnt boot in Acer (this time it is black screen and blinking dash) I think I made something wrong during cloning partitions. I also followed http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/219533-troubleshooting-windows-7-failure-boot.html (bootrec commands and I also have Win7 repair disk but startup repair says that it cannot find errors)

Comment: The last idea I have is to download Windows7 ISO installation and install Win7 and use the product key that I have on the back side of my Asus, would it be OK? I don't need to clone the old HDD, I event don't want it. After cloning I would reset windows to factory settings. I don't have Win7 installation DVD as Asus provides only the recovery partition which is hidden.